# Google serp shows UTF8 encoding error?

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I have a site on this address http://www.kela.nu and in the Google result it shows UTF8 error in the description and in the title. How come? It looks correct with a web browser.

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Akela.nu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some characters was encoded wrong. The mixed encoding made Google confused. When fixing the encoding, Google fixed the rest.